# Increment row reference every 4 rows

Tags: excel

Hi I want to do some multiplication using quarterly weights with annual data,

```
YEAR    Weight             
1960Q1  0.243062075        
1960Q2  0.243510145         
1960Q3  0.251873542         
1960Q4  0.261554238        
1961Q1  0.24091194    
1961Q2  0.246046693    
1961Q3  0.250768104    
1961Q4  0.262273263


Year   Annual Figure
1960   51.81711062    
1961   57.96708711    
1961   62.98765423    
1963   68.48925534


To illustrate (desired output): 
For 1960Q1, I want to get 0.243062075*51.81711062    
For 1960Q2, I want to get 0.243510145*51.81711062    
For 1960Q3, I want to get 0.251873542*51.81711062
...
```

Can someone tell me how to do this in excel? Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: In your annual data there's two rows for 1961, is that just a typo? Should the second row be 1962?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo. It should be 1962.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,4)+0,$A$8:$B$11,2,FALSE)
```

The +0 casts the result to a number for use in the year. Look up the values you want. Not every 4th, What is something changes ?

Comment: Thanks! I used something like this: AC19*VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(AB19,4)),$AF$19:$AG$72,2,0), where the quarterly data is on the left hand side and annual data is on the right hand side, and got it working as well.